# iOS: SQLITE INSERT QUERY ERROR

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite, sql-insert

I am constantly receiving DB error NO Column found inspite i have recreated column and verified it too many times.

Below is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE "ContractorTester" ("ContrTestID" VARCHAR NOT NULL ,"Ack" VARCHAR NOT NULL ,"TesterLName" VARCHAR,"TesterFName" VARCHAR,"GaugeName1" VARCHAR,"GaugeMake1" VARCHAR,"TestCrossConLic" VARCHAR,"CCLicExpDate" VARCHAR,"GaugeSerialNum1" VARCHAR,"GaugeCalibrDate1" VARCHAR,"ContrCompanyName1" VARCHAR,"ContrAddr1" VARCHAR,"ContrCity1" VARCHAR,"ContrState1" VARCHAR,"ContrZip1" VARCHAR,"ContrPhone1" VARCHAR,"Lat" DOUBLE,"Log" DOUBLE,"MCreatedDate" VARCHAR,"MUpdatedDate" VARCHAR,"ActLocalCT
" VARCHAR,"ContrTestTranID" VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY )
```

Below is Insert Query:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ContractorTester ('GaugeName1','GaugeMake1','ContrPhone1','ContrTestTranID','TesterFName','ContrAddr1','ContrCity1','ContrZip1','CCLicExpDate','TestCrossConLic','GaugeCalibrDate1','Ack','TesterLName','ContrTestID','ContrState1','ContrCompanyName1','GaugeSerialNum1','ActLocalCT','Log','Lat') VALUES ('TK-99F','MIDWEST','(847) 111-3314','0','Jack','819 Main1','Lake Zurich','60051','2016-04-17T00:00:00.003','XC3673','2015-04-17T00:00:00.003','0','Skirm','5','IL','American Backflow Prevention Inc.','TG0605','1','0','0')
```

Below is the error:

```
SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ContractorTester ('GaugeName1','GaugeMake1','ContrPhone1','ContrTestTranID','TesterFName','ContrAddr1','ContrCity1','ContrZip1','CCLicExpDate','TestCrossConLic','GaugeCalibrDate1','Ack','TesterLName','ContrTestID','ContrState1','ContrCompanyName1','GaugeSerialNum1','ActLocalCT','Log','Lat') VALUES ('TK-99F','MIDWEST','(847) 111-3314','0','Jack','819 Main1','Lake Zurich','60051','2016-04-17T00:00:00.003','XC3673','2015-04-17T00:00:00.003','0','Skirm','5','IL','American Backflow Prevention Inc.','TG0605','1','0','0') [ table ContractorTester has no column named ActLocalCT ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

Please any one review and let me know what is the wrong in above Queries.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ContractorTester
```

with

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ContractorTester VALUES
```

Without the `VALUES` the list in parens is the list of columns to insert into, not the list of values to insert.